# File uploading to invisible file_fields with watir / watir-webdriver in ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm trying to automate uploading a file to an HTML filepicker using watir / watir-webdriver in Ruby like so:

```
@browser.form(:action => '/submit').file_fields[0].set "/myfile.txt"
```

But this throws the following errors which are similar when using different browsers:

SAFARI (initialized with `@browser = Watir::Browser.new :safari`)

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated
```

FIREFOX: (initialized with `@browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox`)

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

I've been able to get this working before but now it seems to be not working. There are multiple `file_fields` on the page, but in fact **none of them** are visible:

```
 @browser.file_fields.map{|x| x.visible?}
=> [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]
```

I don't understand why these aren't visible since I've never had this problem before. Is there a way to force them to be visible or another technique I can use?

Versions:
`watir-5.0.0`
`watir-webdriver-0.8.0`
`ruby 2.1.2p95`

Comment: Can you post the HTML in question?  If the element has a `display:none` property (and a unique id), you can do something like this: `b.execute_script("document.getElementById('YOUR_ID_HERE').style.display='block';")`.

Comment: Here is the HTML for the input: `<input type="file" id="file-upload" class="upload" capture accept="txt">` Its computed styles are: `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 65px;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: normal;
height: 374px;
left: 0px;
line-height: normal;
opacity: 1;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
width: 300px;
z-index: 3;`

I used `@browser.execute_script` successfully, but in ruby, `visible?` remains false and I am unable to interact with the element in Watir.

Answer (score 0):

u can force interaction with a hidden element like so:

```
@browser.hidden('selector')
```

or if u select more than one hidden element:

```
@browser.hiddens('selector').first
```

Comment: Are you sure that this would work? If I recall correctly, `hidden` is for returning `<input type="hidden">` tags. It will not return `<input type="file">`.